# will Airline Power Adapter work in a car lighter as well?

Tags: macbook-pro, accessories

Trying to see if I would buy this accessory with a new MacBook Air 11'', does anyone know if the [Airline Power Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB441Z/A) work exactly as a charger that we normally use in the car?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it says on the package that it was specifically designed for those Airline plugs and will not work in cars.

Plus, it will not charge your MacBook, it will only power it to run.

Cheers!